# Golang Return a different Struct based on some logic and unmarshal to that struct

Tags: go

I have a case where I'm I have to support multiple versions.  Each one has different data so I create 2 structs.  Based on the version I will return 1 of the structs.  Once I identify which struct, I then would request the data and Unmarshal into the struct.  However, Since that struct satisfies an interface, I dont think the unmarshal is working correctly.  I always get the zero value for the sctruct

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

// Ten300 ...
type Ten300 struct {
    Map     string `json:"map"`
    Enabled string `json:"enabled"`
}

// Ten400 ...
type Ten400 struct {
    Block1 int `json:"block_1"`
    Block2 int `json:"block_2"`
}

// NET ...
type NET struct {
    CMD Commands
    S   TenIft
}

// Commands ...
type Commands struct {
    Get string
}

// TenIft ...
type TenIft interface {
    Get(string) error
}

// Get ...
func (n *Ten300) Get(module string) error {
    fmt.Println("Ten300", "Get()")
    return nil
}

// Get ...
func (n *Ten400) Get(module string) error {
    fmt.Println("Ten400", "Get()")
    n.Block2 = 100
    return nil
}

// TenGen easy to read fun type
type TenGen func() NET

// VersionSetup is a map of possible version
var VersionSetup = map[string]TenGen{
    "3.0.0": func() NET {
        return NET{
            CMD: Commands{
                Get: "getConfig",
            },
            S: &Ten300{},
        }
    },
    "4.0.0": func() NET {
        return NET{
            CMD: Commands{
                Get: "getSettings",
            },
            S: &Ten400{},
        }
    },
}

const input300 = `{
    "map": "one",
    "enabled": "two"
}`

const input400 = `{
    "block_1": 1,
    "block_2": 2
}`

// Setup ...
func (n *NET) Setup() error {
    // This Switch is just to use hard coded data
    var input string
    switch n.S.(type) {
    case *Ten400:
        input = input400
    case *Ten300:
        input = input300
    }

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), n.S)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("returning err:", err)
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("n.s type: %T\nn.s value: %+v\n", n.S, n.S)
    n.S.Get("xxx")
    return nil
}

func main() {

    version := "3.0.0"
    if f, ok := VersionSetup[version]; ok {
        net := f()

        err := net.Setup()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    version = "4.0.0"
    if f, ok := VersionSetup[version]; ok {
        net := f()

        err := net.Setup()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

}
```

Added [go-playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RWW2l9S9323) ... this seems to work, but is this the best solution?

Comment: It will be easier for us to understand if you can create a go playground with a run-able example.

Comment: 1. `TEN` has no field `n` your cod would not compile 2. `Configure` works on a non pointer receiver so modifications of `t` done in `Config` do not change the value of the `t` you call Configure on. 3. You probably should export your  fields. I urge you to redo the Tour of Go and always come up with a runnable example.

Comment: Updated code... it does Unmarshal to the correct struct but is this the best way?